# Markdown-created links in comments aren't nofollowed

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, nofollow

```
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn) for more info
```

won't be nofollowed, unlike

```
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn for more info
```

which will.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn) for more info. Hey, it works. Is that new?

Comment: @Kobi it's a few weeks old, but fairly unused.

Comment: Plain links **do** have the `nofollow` attribute.

Comment: @json: My point exactly. (Although nitpicking: the attribute is `rel`)

Comment: HTML modafuka!? Do *you* **speak** it?`</obligatory_daily_pulp_fiction_reference>`

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46447/markdown-created-links-in-comments-arent-nofollowed) for more info. Edit: Awesome! I'm glad this was added (also, this explains to me how this was being done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good catch, also I centralized the "when should we nofollow this?" logic.